# It is secure or possible or not if I used function or class in CodeIgniter to generate table to store my user information?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, codeigniter

I'm try to create my own algorithm to generate table rather than insert their data into existing table in database. I'm using **WAMP Server** with latest PHP, Mysql, Apache version to store my employer and employee information specially they will have one table to store Jobs information and I want to use CodeIgniter class to generate it(table) for each user (employee, employer) when their click generate their table for their job information after that their can input,update,delete, as they want to post their jobs in its table'row or cell or column.

**Should I build table generator to create one table for each user to store their jobs information that is avoid Database slow down when my job table got more than 5000 rows or more than this in only one table?**

**Should I store my information if I need more than 5000 rows of my data into only on table in Mysql Db?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking it's not good practice to dynamically create tables with PHP. Your tables will be hard to maintain in the long run. There are reasons other than security to avoid this, but yes, it is possible.

Instead of creating a new `jobs` table for each user, why not just create a single jobs table with a user_id row so you know which jobs belong to which users.

Comment: Yes it is not meter to make relative from table user and jobs table I can do it but I wonder to store much more data or rows in only table because I used to store only 4500 rows per table and when I query data it always slow down that why I want to generate table for each user avoid to store much rows in one table

Comment: If your tables are slowing down significantly after only 4k rows you may want to consider structuring them better. Make sure you've go the proper indexes, etc.

Comment: Sorry Adelphia,
I don't understand your statement **Make sure you've go the proper indexes**. what that is mean and what should I do? or this cause from my PHP coding right

I just follow by Codeigniter structure 
1,Create query function in Model (using select * in msyql using Codeigniter medoth)
2,Create controller in My Controller 
3, View it in view by using function if(): and foreach(): for query all the properties

Comment: unfortunately I'm not familiar with CodeIgniter so I'm not sure what you're talking about, but do a quick Google search for "Optimizing MySQL tables" you'll find something useful :)

Comment: Thanks you very much @Adelphaia for your commend and I will try to find this method and build my table generator for my stuff